# Could something prevent us from ever existing?

Tags: existence, universe, multiverse

There are several ideas regarding the creation of our universe that suggest that our universe emerged from another one (eternal inflation suggesting our universe is the byproduct of an inflationary period in another universe, Avi Loeb’s idea that our universe was created in some alien lab, or just simulation hypothesis). My understanding is that each universe would have slightly different laws of physics.

My question is that if this idea were indeed the case, could some event that hasn’t occurred yet in another universe prevent our existence, in essence making it so we never existed?(Ex. some sort of time travel or time reversal mechanism)

Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question, but I would appreciate an answer!

Comment: Please make clear the mechanism of causal interaction between the universes you consider.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Time travel and overwriting history is purely a fictional idea. If our history were overwritten such that we no longer exist, it's probably just a question of semantics and context as to whether we ever existed.